# Как переустановить APEX Listener 2.0.0 для APEX 3.2.1?

Tags: oracle, rest, listener, oracle-apex

Я хочу установить Oracle Apex Listener 2.0.0 для apex 3.2.1 , чтобы пользоваться Restful data Service  , но когда я зашёл на ссылку http://localhost:8080/apex/listenerConfigure то мне сразу написалось "The requested URL /apex/listenerConfigure was not found on this server".

Но как всегда у меня возникли проблемы , как показано на следующей картинке:

1. https://community.oracle.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/2-13889456-186709/port_error.png

Я уже как бы могу здесь тока догадаться , что порт 8080 уже занят apex сервером и таким образом он уже не может быть использован одновременно и к серверу Oracle APEX Listener. Я хочу установить мой Apex Listner сервер в автономном режиме( standalone mone). Мне не нужны никакие апачи вида Tomcat , Weblogic , Glassfish и.т.д. , без них итак сервер развернётся по умолчанию). Как мне исправить эту ошибку , что у меня на консоле ?

2. Когда я установил APEX 3.2.1 и Apex listener 2.0.0 У меня не было файла для конфигурации сервиса restful apex_rest_config.sql которое необходимо для успешной установки и настройки Oracle APEX Listener. Многие на форуме Oracle community пишут , что это из за того , что это связано с истечением срока поддержки apex 3.2.1. Но всё же , если вы знаете , где эти файлы-компоненты , необходимые для установки restful сервиса находятся или они хотя бы в github , то прошу дайте мне ссылку на эти ресурсы , чтобы я мог их скачать особенно apex_rest_config.sql для установки APEX Listener 2.0.0
3. Скажите : APEX 3.2.1 поддерживается для apex listener 2.0.0 или нет ?

В дополнении скажите мне ещё , что мне надо сделать , чтобы успешно установить APEX Listener ? Более точный порядок действий. А то мне кажется есть чтото , что мне ещё помешает полноценно установить этот restful.